# javascript - Convesion of multiple codes from user input and display of converted characters as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, converters, user-input

This is the continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354066/javascript-how-to-show-value-from-object-by-matching-user-input-to-its-key).
I succeeded to make a script which converts one code from user input to a Unicode Code Point and then converts it to the corresponding character from the special hieroglyphic font. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<input id="userInput" name="userInput" type="text">
<button id="convert">Click me!</button>
<div id="hieroglyphs">
    <p id="AbydosWord"></p>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#convert").click(function(){
            var GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint = {
                        "A1"    :"995328",
                        "A1A"   :"995329",
                        "A1B"   :"995330",
                        "A1C"   :"995331",
                        "A2"    :"995332",
                        "A2A"   :"995333",
                    };
            var userInput = $("#userInput").val();
            if (userInput in GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint) {
            var convertedCode = String.fromCodePoint(GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint[userInput]);
                $("#AbydosWord").empty();
                $("#AbydosWord").append(convertedCode);
                } else {
                    $("#AbydosWord").empty();
                    $("#AbydosWord").append("?");
                }
            });
            });
</script>
</body>
```

Now I want to make a function which will use user input in the shape of multiple codes (e.g. A1 A2A A1C) and converts it to the string of hieroglyphs. This is where I got so far, but for now, it does not work.

```
<body>
<input id="userInput" name="userInput" type="text">
<button id="convert">Click me!</button>
<div id="hieroglyphs">
    <p id="AbydosWord"></p>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#convert").click(function(){
            var GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint = {
                        "A1"    :"995328",
                        "A1A"   :"995329",
                        "A1B"   :"995330",
                        "A1C"   :"995331",
                        "A2"    :"995332",
                        "A2A"   :"995333",
                    };
            var finalCodeHolder = "";
            var userInput = $("#userInput").val();
            var userInputSplit = userInput.split(" ");
            for (i = 0; i < userInputSplit.length; index++) {
                if (userInputSplit[i] in GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint) {
                var convertedCode = String.fromCodePoint(GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint[userInputSplit[i]]);
                finalCodeHolder.push(convertedCode);
                } else {
                    var convertedCode = "?";
                    finalCodeHolder.push(convertedCode);
                }
            }
            $("#AbydosWord").append(finalCodeHolder);
            });
            });
</script>
</body>
```

I guess that is the problem with `convertedCode` array and `.push()` method. I would like your input on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I finally did it.

Here is the solution:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#convert").click(function(){
            var GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint = {
                        "A1"    :"995328",
                        "A1A"   :"995329",
                        "A1B"   :"995330",
                        "A1C"   :"995331",
                        "A2"    :"995332",
                        "A2A"   :"995333",
                        "A3"    :"995334",
                        "A3A"   :"995335",
                        "A3B"   :"995336",
                    };
            var finalCodeHolder = "";
            var userInput = $("#userInput").val();
            var userInputSplit = userInput.split(" ");
            $("#AbydosWord").empty();
                for (i = 0; i < userInputSplit.length; i++) {
                    if (userInputSplit[i] in GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint) {
                    var convertedCode = String.fromCodePoint(GardinerToUnicodeCodePoint[userInputSplit[i]]);
                    $("#AbydosWord").append(convertedCode);
                    } else {
                        var convertedCode = "?";
                        $("#AbydosWord").append(convertedCode);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now I will try to find a way to make it live - I am trying to avoid button click for conversion, it should be like regular typing of text.